# Set relative path of baml/xaml in *.g.cs using MarkupCompilePass1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, msbuild, baml

Currently I'm compiling `xaml` to `baml` using `MarkupCompilePass1`. This is working pretty well, besides of the relative paths which points to the `baml/xaml` ressources. For example let's assume the xaml file is in the directory `ui/controls/test.xaml`, than the generated code (`test.g.cs`) should look like this:

```
_contentLoaded = true;
System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/Sample01;component/ui/controls/test.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

#line 1 "test.xaml"
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
```

But it currently looks like this:

```
_contentLoaded = true;
System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/Sample01;component/test.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative); // <--- Here is the problem

#line 1 "test.xaml"
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
```

How can I solve this issue?  The `Uri` is not complete, becuase it does not contain `/ui/controls`.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the current code which generates the `baml` and `*.g.cs`

```
foreach (var _xaml in xamlSources)
{
    // Relative path to the xaml file
    _xaml.RelativePath = _xaml.RelativePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(_xaml.Path.Replace(CXUIBuildEngine.ProjectRoot, ""));

    _task = new MarkupCompilePass1();
    _task.BuildEngine = BuildEngine;
    _task.RequirePass2ForMainAssembly = false;
    _task.OutputType = "library";

    // List of xaml to compile, im this case just one,
    // because only one output is allowed so we have to set
    // the specific output per compile process...
    _task.PageMarkup = new[] { new XamlItem(_xaml.Path) };

    // Set default namespace
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CXUIBuildEngine.RootNamespace))
    {
        _task.RootNamespace = CXUIBuildEngine.RootNamespace;
    }

    // Set default options
    _task.AssemblyName = CXUIBuildEngine.AssemblyName;
    _task.Language = "cs";

    // !!! Here we combine the output path with the relative path,
    // !!! This is maybe already the fault
    _task.OutputPath = Path.Combine(TempOutputDirectory, _xaml.RelativePath);

    // Add all references as XamlItem
    if (CXUIBuildEngine.References != null)
    {
        _task.References = CXUIBuildEngine.References.Select(item => new XamlItem(item.Location)).ToArray();
    }

    if (!_task.Execute())
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: *"I'm compiling `xaml` to `baml` using `MarkupCompilePass1`"* - can you show how you doing it? To me it looks like you are compiling files as if root (base) folder is where xaml is located. You have to compile using project root (base) folder, then it should generate proper paths.

Comment: @Sinatr I added the generator code. Does this help? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Check how `OutputPath` looks like, try to use relative path there.

Comment: But then I need to set something like a workindirectory for the compiler, is that possible? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Sinatr Setting some metadata seems to help. What do you thing about this solution?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a *question and answer* site. If you find an answer yourself, you should post it *as an answer*, not *edit* it into your question and change the title.

Comment: Following on from Damien's good advice, I have reverted the answer that was left in the question. Please be willing to leave these in a good readable condition for future readers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `Link` and `LogicalName` in the `XamlPages` / `Items` seems to help:

```
var _item = new XamlItem(_xaml.Path);
_item.SetMetadata("Link", _xaml.RelativePath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(_xaml.Path));
_item.SetMetadata("LogicalName", _xaml.RelativePath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(_xaml.Path));
_task.PageMarkup = new[] { _item };
```

This properties are only saved in a `Dictioary<string, string>` inside of the item.